# Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $f(x)=f(4-x)$ , then find the minimum number of roots of $f''(x)=0$ in $[0,4]$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, rolles-theorem

Let $f(x)$ be a non-constant twice differentiable function defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$ such that $f(x)=f(4-x)$ and $f(x)=0$ has at least two distinct repeated roots in $(2,4)$, then find the minimum number of roots of $f''(x)=0$ in $[0,4]$.

**My Attempt**

Clearly $f(x)$ is symmetrical about $x=2$. So $f'(2)=0$.

On $(2,4)$ we have two points ,say $x=\alpha$ and $x=\beta$ where $f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)=f(\beta)=f'(\beta)=0$.

So between $x=\alpha$ and $x=\beta$ we will have some $x=\gamma$ for which $f'(\gamma)=0$.

So $f'(x)=0$ has $4$ roots on $[2,4]$. So $f''(x)=0$ has at least three roots in $(2,4)$

Since $f(x)$ is symmetrical about $x=2$, there will be at least three roots in $(0,2)$

So in all there should be at least $6$ roots of $f''(x)=0$ on $[0,4]$

But the given answer is $4$. Am I overcounting some case

Comment: What are 'two distinct repeated roots' in the question?

Comment: $\cos ((2-x)\pi)$ has this property. As far as I can see there are only $4$ roots of $f''(x)=0$ in $[0,4]$ in this case.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\cos((2-x)\pi)$ does not have any repeated root on $(2,4)$. However $\cos^2((2-x)\pi)$ has

Comment: Sorry. my comment was based purely on the question in the title.

Comment: Why must $f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)$?

Comment: I have taken $\alpha$ to be one of the repeated roots.

Comment: @Maverick $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ not $f'.$ I don't see any reason as to why $f'(\alpha) =0 .$ Can you explain?

Comment: If $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^2g(x)$ then $f(\alpha)=f’(\alpha)=0$

Comment: I see, I missed the word "repeated."